# how to export Visual Studio 2013 project into sourcecode

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Could anyone please help and tell me how to export visual studio project into source code. My client has asked me if they can see a file with source code, so that they are able to recreate the application by using the source code only.

Could you please advise and tell me how I can export the visual studio project into source code, which will include all of the files, code and etc.

Comment: The project and its files (.vb etc) *are* the source code. What are you really asking? Do you have the executable but *not* the actual project from which it was created?

Comment: so .VB files are the source code for both designer and code view.

Comment: I think you should check the beginner courses in Microsoft's Virtual Academy, like [this one](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/vb-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-8297)

Comment: Thank you for your Help. I did know that Vb. files are the source code however someone told me that their is another way to do this. Looks like I just need to give them the vb. files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you go to the Visual Studio Project directory or the directory where you save your Visual Studio Projects/Solutions you will see a directory for each of your Projects. Generally all the files in this directory are the source code for a project.

Comment: What about if I have access database and want to see sourcecode for that as well.; Can I export it into a SQL.file. Help please?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure they don't mean check it into source code ***control***?

For example you can link your Visual Studio project up to TFS, check in your code and other developers can download and work on it in Visual Studio
https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs

Just a thought

Comment: What a guess you made :) I was totally confused with this question